# validation of an integer parameter in C

Tags: c, validation, limit

I was told one of the best practice with Functions with parameters is to perform parameter validation.
 So for string checking null or empty and so on.

I am creating a List and for that creating a node which accepts integer value. I am checking the value against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` but from what I read int value is always going to be between this. If I pass a long long val, in the called function with `signature node* create(int val)` - value gets converted to int range and falls within.

Question : if val of long is being passed, is there a way to detect it and not let the node be created ? Currently it gets created

Question : for a standard int what else checking of parameter do I need to perform to write a robust code ?

*My code Snippet*

```
long long vall = 88888888888888; 
create(vall);     // for such case I don't want node to be created

node* create(int val)
{
    if (val <= INT_MIN || val >= INT_MAX)
    {
        printf(" values are out of range");
    }
    node *pnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    if(pnode == NULL)
    {
        printf(" node creation failed \n");
    }

    pnode->pnext = NULL;
    pnode->val = val;

    return pnode;
}
```

Comment: It doesn't make any sense to check `int` against it's limits, as by definition it can't be out of them. You need to check it against the values that are permitted by your function. If it is working on the whole range of `int`s, there is no reason to check the bounds.

Comment: OP would do that when "If I pass a long long val", before using it in `int` context. But the function argument must be `long long` or the value has already been truncated.

Comment: You should split validation to different function, accepting greater range, validate, and then call Your function (if it validates).

Comment: @EugeneSh. Yes, that's what I felt and mentioned that checking against max and min seem redundant. But as Weather Vane mentioned what if I get a long long val passed, is there a way for me to discard it

Comment: @oneday The value won't be seen inside the function, as it is already converted into `int`. You will have to do the check beforehand.

Comment: @JustMe - So if I understand it correctly, suggestion is creating a seperate function which take long long per se as parameter and check if its within range of int ?  - But if another such function exists within create function - which I have mentioned, value is already spoiled, can you point me to snippet of ur suggestion ?

Comment: For internal functions where I control all the callers, I am inclined to use assertions rather than `if` statements for argument checks.  In fact, I tend to put in an assertion wherever my code makes an assumption that I think is safe, but where the reason it is safe is not obvious.

Comment: @EugeneSh. - Agreed. And I think from all the answers I am getting not much validation needs to be done if intention is to accept all int value.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - Sure, will keep that thing in mind.

Comment: @oneday, I intended to write reply, but You got it right in last comment. You would need a wrapper only if You wanted some specific action, like log value too high or something.

Comment: @JustMe - Thanks for confirming. If you or Eugene can post in answer I can go ahead and accept it and close the thread. I think I am clear now.

Comment: if you do not want the node to created if the passed in value is outside the desired range, then why is the posted code, after displaying an error message, going right ahead and creating the node?

Comment: in general, calling functions and the associated called functions have a 'software contract' between them.   Therefore, under such conditions, (where some user or file or socket is not supplying the value, there is no need to waste CPU cycles and code space verifying some parameter that the caller (due to the software contract) will never send.   Clearly defined functions interfaces, etc make keeping that software contract much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if val of `long` is being passed, is there a way to detect it and not let the node be created ?

Change function signature to `long` or `long long`, etc.

```
// declare/define function first
node* create(long long val);

long long vall = 88888888888888; 
create(vall);     // for such case I don't want node to be created

node* create(long long val) {
    // if (val <= INT_MIN || val >= INT_MAX) {
    if (val < INT_MIN || val > INT_MAX) {
        fprintf(stderr, " %lld out of int range\n", val);

        return NULL;
        // Return or exit, do not continue with the following code 
    }

    // node *pnode = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    // Suggest alternative
    node *pnode = malloc(sizeof *pnode);
    ...
    // Adding an explicit cast useful to quiet pedantic warnings
    pnode->val = (int) val;
    ...
```

Note: With original code, many compilers with all warnings enabled will warn about the below (without knowing the value of `vall`) as a narrowing of range.

```
node* create(int val)
long long vall = ...; 
create(vall);
```

> for a standard `int` what else checking of parameter do I need to perform to write a robust code ?

Nothing, unless the function can only use a sub-range of `int`.  All `int` values are in the range `[INT_MIN ... IN_MAX]`.  [@Eugene Sh.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37887626/validation-of-an-integer-parameter-in-c/37888338#comment63230052_37887626)

Answer (score 1):

You may create one more function with the same name but different arguments list:

```
node* create(long long val);
```

If you pass a value of type `long long`, this function will run, not `node* create(int val);`. So, you can handle the case, when you pass `long` as a parameter, through creating another function.

As for your second questinon, I should say, that you don't need to check your `int` value against `INT_MIN` and `INT_MAX` boundaries, because **it will never be out of these bounds. `INT_MAX` and `INT_MIN` are ACTUAL BOUNDARIES OF `int` TYPE ITSELF.**

Check your `int` value considering your needs (needs of your function).

You need to check passed strings for `NULL`, because if you try to access such string, your program will collapse. But when you pass an `int` value, it *will have an assigned value anyway.*